# decreasing memory usage of indexing a Lucene document

Tags: java, memory, lucene

Right now, my documents in lucene can have very very large values in one field (from 0 to say hundreds of MB).

I am using Lucene 3.1.0, I create documents like this:

```
doc = new Document();
Field field = new Field(fieldname, VERYLARGEVALUE, store, tokenize, storevector);
doc.add(field);
```

Where VERYLARGEVALUE is a String in memory. I am thinking that maybe writing VERYLARGEVALUE to a file while it is being created (it is created by extracting text from a number of sources so it is incremental), and then using:

```
Field field = Field(String name, Reader reader, Field.TermVector termVector); 
doc.add(field);
```

Where reader reads from the File I wrote VERYLARGEVALUE to.

Will this decrease the memory requirement or VERYLARGEVALUE will be eventually read to memory sooner or later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the Lucene code, the `Reader` you pass into `Field` ultimately gets passed to the `TokenStream` that tokenizes your data (namely in `DocInverterPerField`). So your plan should definitely save memory since it'll stream directly from that reader to do its indexing. You'll like want to use a `BufferedReader` on top of the `FileReader` for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

java.io.Reader implementations were designed to efficiently read character streams by reading portions of the stream into memory. (See the [read(char[] cbuf)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28char%5B%5D%29) API.)  So I'd say "yes", using a Reader would decrease your memory overhead

Comment: surely, but here the devil is in how the Reader is used when reading the doc and later indexing it. If the whole String is read into memory at some point it is no good to me in my case.

Comment: The Reader content seems to be getting added to the index. So long as you call commit() frequently (and don't use a memory based index) memory requirements should be manageable.